# How do I correctly indent this line of code?

Tags: python, selenium, coding-style, indentation, pep8

I read a little bit of PEP 8's conventions and I wondered how to correctly indent this long line of code.

`WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.LWmhU._0aCwM > div.yPP5B > div > div._01UL2 > div > div:nth-child(1) > a"))).click()`

My try:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, """
        #react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.LWmhU._0aCwM 
        > div.yPP5B > div > div._01UL2 > div > div:nth-child(1) > a
        """))
).click()
```

Comment: Share relevant HTML and what was the error faced ?

Comment: There is no error i just want to know the most pythonic way of indenting this line of code.

Comment: this is really a bad locator `#react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.LWmhU._0aCwM 
        > div.yPP5B > div > div._01UL2 > div > div:nth-child(1) > a` if you can share HTML then I can give you bit more reliable locator that will help you with consistency and indentation

Comment: I honestly just want to know how i correctly indent long strings

Comment: Probably opinion-based. The additional whitespace doesn't affect the CSS, but you could also break the string into multiple string literals that are concatenated by the parser.